# that which belongs to or is connected with her

Tags: relative-clauses

> that **which** belongs to or is connected with her ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/hers)’s Learner’s)

'Though ‘*which*’ can be replaced by ‘*that*’ in relative constructions' they say, when it is placed after ‘*that*’ I wonder if aforesaid can be applied as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *that which* cannot be replaced with *that that*:

> **that which** belongs to or is connected with her
>   **that *that** belongs to or is connected with her

See *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* p.1053:

> (d) *That which* and *all who*: obligatory *wh*
>
> ```
> [63] i. That [which we so carefully created] he has wantonly destroyed.
>     ii. All [who heard her speak] were deeply impressed by her sincerity.
> ```
>
> The very formal *that which* ("what") cannot be replaced by either *that that* or *that*, and when pronominal *all* applies to people *who* is required (cf. **all that heard her speak*).

This conflicts with a rule sometimes given by prescriptive grammarians (although many *which*-hunters describe this case as an exception).  [Geoff Pullum has written about this on Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2425).

Comment: Thank you. Somehow the sounds, 'that that,' rattles not beautifully even on my, alien's, tongue.

Answer (score 2):

> that which belongs to or is connected with her

The *that* in your example is not a relative pronoun but a demonstrative pronoun, meaning approximately "that thing", so it cannot be replaced by *which*, which has no demonstrative sense. You cannot paraphrase as

> which that belongs to or is connected with her

which is not meaningful English.

Although relative *that*, demonstrative *that*, and subordinator *that* all derive historically from the same OE word, the neuter nominative/accusative determiner *þæt*, they are effectively different words today, having different relationships to other words in the lexicon.